# How to include a .xaml script inside of a .xml file in Xamarin?

Tags: xml, xaml, xamarin

I'm working on an Android App inside of Visual Studio and using Xamarin. I've created a .xmal file which serves as a footer and I am trying to implement it inside of my main .xml script like this:

```
<ArchaismDictionaryAndroidApp.Resources.layout.footer
    android:layout_width = "match_parent"
    android:layout_height = "100dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom = "true"
    android:largeHeap="true"/>
```

The tag is the namespace.class of the C# script which comes with the .xaml file. When I try to run my app, though, I get this error message:

> Android.Views.InflateException: 'Binary XML file line #2: Binary XML
>   file line #2: Error inflating class
>   ArchaismDictionaryAndroidApp.Resources.layout.footer'

I get it on this line of code: `SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);`

What are some of the probable causes for this problem? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Strictly speaking you can't. However you can add a fragment to your xml file and then convert XAML to fragment using the code and assign to it.